What sort of connector is this (Gtech robotic lawnmower)?
I am trying to get a replacement battery for my Gtech robotic lawnmower but they don’t sell the batteries (they come pre-assembled from the factory apparently).
I have opened the mower up and the battery connector is the one on the right-hand side (white).
I have been able to get a battery of the same size and specification, but its connector is smaller (the left-hand side black one)
What type is the white connector? Is it possible to get one or an adaptor that will allow me to use the new battery in the mower?


No such adapter will exists unless you solder one yourself. Why not simply cut the wires of which ever connector is inconvenient and replace it with the other one though? These would likely be some flavour of Molex.. measure the pitch (pin-to-pin distance) with calipers.

I'd also strongly recommend that you post the spec of the original battery and the replacement here as a separate question, to verify that they are compatible, before using it. Wrong battery -> charger on fire -> house on fire -> no insurance. But the lawn is neatly cut at least.

Thanks for your advice - i'll post a seperate question about the battery spec

@braindeadclown where did you purchase the battery from? I’ve disassembled mine to diagnose some issues but struggled to understand what the white cable is for attached to the bms


What type is the white connector?

The white connector is a TE Value-Lok
The female housing's part number is TE 1586105.
https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/te-connectivity-amp-connectors/1586105-3/1833590
The contacts are sold separately.
Here is the matching male housing: TE 1586103-3
https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/te-connectivity-amp-connectors/1586103-3/1833593

Is it possible to get one or an [*adapter] that will allow me to use the new battery in the mower?

No. What makes more sense is to get the male mate for the white connector and replace the black connector (a Molex Micro Fit). Or vice-versa.
